# How to Use Both ScalingFunctions and PlotRange

Tags: plotting

How do I use both `ScalingFunctions` and `PlotRange` with `ListLinePlot`. It seems that the moment I use `ScalingFunctions`, `PlotRange` is completely ignored.

Example:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {6, 28, 75},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, Automatic}
 ]
```

The plot I get has an x-axis that ranges from 1 to 3. I want 0 to 20.

I know that I can change the range of x values in plotting functions like `ListLinePlot` with `DataRange`, but that doesn't help me. I want to extend the range of the x-axis slightly beyond the range of the data values.

Comment: I think your problem stems from the inclusion of $0$ in the range for a logarithmic axis, which probably causes the rest of the PlotRange specification to be ignored. Try using a small non-zero value instead. More in general, your purpose could be more appropriately achieved using `PlotRangePadding` as well.

Comment: You're right. If I start the plot range from 1, the problem goes away. `PlotRangePadding` doesn't really help me, because it's not padding I want. I want a constant plot range and use the code for different data sets, which may only have data points in some areas of the range.

Comment: If you know the minimum `x`, or a lower bound, that you will encounter in your data sets, you could use that in `PlotRange` instead of `1` or `0`.  The number `0` corresponds to `-Infinity` on the `Log2` scale, which cannot be plotted.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain what's happening.  Fixing it can be done as @MarcoB explained in a comment, by passing positive numbers for the `PlotRange`.  These could be determined in advance if all the data sets to be plotted are known.  The basic usage rule to be added is this:

> *With any sort of log scaling, `PlotRange` settings that contain zero or negative numbers will be rejected and an `Automatic` setting will be used. This applies to any other sort of scaling, if the scaling of the plot range results in non-real intervals.*

#### What's happening?

Plotting changes from version to version, so here is the version this explanation is based on:

```
$Version
(* "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)
```

With the following code, you can track the changes to the plot range.  First the automatic settings such as `Automatic` and `Full` are expanded to give a complete `PlotRange` setting of the form `{{_, _}, {_, _}}`.  Next the ranges are scaled.  We see that the first part of `PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, Automatic}` is scaled to `{-∞, Log2[20]}`.  What happens next is this range setting is rejected if it contains `∞ | -∞ | _Complex | Indeterminate`.  It is then reset to `Automatic`, and the range recalculated, which results in the range based just on the data.

```
Block[{System`ProtoPlotDump`sPrint, prnt},
 SetAttributes[prnt, HoldAll];
 prnt[e_] := Module[{name, ok},
   ok = Quiet@ Check[name = SymbolName@Unevaluated@e; True, False];
   If[ok && StringMatchQ[name, ___ ~~ "range" ~~ ___],
     Print[HoldForm[e] -> e]]
   ];
 System`ProtoPlotDump`sPrint = prnt;
 ListLinePlot[{6, 28, 75}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, Automatic}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Interestingly, the range is not padded above, but it is if in the original call to `ListLinePlot`, the `PlotRange` option is omitted.

```
Block[{System`ProtoPlotDump`sPrint, prnt},
 SetAttributes[prnt, HoldAll];
 prnt[e_] := Module[{name, ok},
   ok = Quiet@Check[name = SymbolName@Unevaluated@e; True, False];
   If[ok && StringMatchQ[name, ___ ~~ "range" ~~ ___],
    Print[HoldForm[e] -> e]]
   ];
 System`ProtoPlotDump`sPrint = prnt;
 ListLinePlot[{6, 28, 75}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Example workaround

Some sample data sets:

```
SeedRandom[1];  (* for reproducibility *)
foo = 4;
{data1, data2, data3} = Table[
   Transpose@
    {Sort@ RandomReal[2^{RandomReal[-4], RandomReal[4]}, foo],  (* x-coordinates *) 
     RandomReal[RandomReal[100], foo++]},                       (* y-coordinates *)
   {3}];
```

Calculate the minimum `PlotRange`:

```
pr = {MinMax[{data1, data2, data3}[[All, All, 1]]], All}
(*  {{0.186413, 7.90499}, All}  *)
```

Plot (similar to above, there is no padding; if desired, add padding manually):

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}, PlotRange -> pr, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.05]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]